# what function to use in ruby to simulate a for

Tags: ruby, for-loop

I need a function that can simulate the C++ `for` statement.
I want something that I can give a starting point, an end and another variable that will say how much to increment at a time.

For example if I tell it to start at `10`, end at `1` and increment `2` at a time, it will generate `10, 8, 6, 4, 2`.

Comment: isn't there a `range` function?

Comment: You cannot increment 2 from 10 towards 1. You either have to increment by -2 or decrement by 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want `step`.  It is used like this:

```
10.step(1, -2) do |x|
    puts x
end
```

This results in:

```
10
8
6
4
2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
1.9.3p125 :007 > (1..10).step(2).reverse_each { |i| p i }
10
8
6
4
2
```

Comment: solution of @vacawama is  shorter, reverse_each is just one more way to do it.